Python Turtle Graphics freezing and not responding
This code ran 4-5 times without a problem, but it does not anymore. Whenever I run the file, the window for Python Turtle Graphics stops responding,(freezes) and eventually crashes.
import random
import turtle

import package

running = True

words = ['aardvark', 'camel', 'baboon']
found_letters = []
hangman = package.Man(turtle.Turtle())

word = str(random.choice(words))
listed_word = []

for character in word:
    listed_word.append(character)


blanks = ''
lives = 6

for character in word:
    blanks += '_'

print(blanks)

while running:
    guess = str(input(f"Enter your letter: ")).lower()

    if len(guess) == 1:
        if guess in listed_word:
            for index, letter in enumerate(listed_word):
                if letter == guess:
                    blanks_list = list(blanks)

                    blanks_list[index] = guess
                    blanks = ''.join(blanks_list)

            print(blanks)

            if blanks == word:
                print("You win!")
                turtle.done()
                running = False
        else:
            if lives != 0:
                lives -= 1
                hangman.check(lives)

            if lives > 0:
                print(f"You have {lives} lives left.")
            else:
                print("Game over!")
                turtle.done()
                running = False
    else:
        pass

I'm not sure if the issue is calling the check function inside of a loop, or it initializing the class.
Here's the 'package' file with the 'Man' class.
import turtle


class Man:
    def __init__(self, turtle_class: turtle.Turtle):
        self.pen = turtle_class
        self.pen.penup()

        self.pen.goto(0, 100)

    def circle(self):
        self.pen.pendown()

        self.pen.circle(30)

        self.pen.penup()

    def body(self):
        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.right(90)

        self.pen.forward(60)
        self.pen.penup()

    def left_leg(self):
        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.left(30)

        self.pen.forward(60)
        self.pen.penup()

        self.pen.back(60)
        self.pen.right(30)

    def right_leg(self):
        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.right(30)

        self.pen.forward(60)
        self.pen.penup()

        self.pen.back(60)
        self.pen.left(30)

    def left_arm(self):
        self.pen.left(180)
        self.pen.forward(46.6666666667)

        self.pen.left(90)
        self.pen.left(30)

        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.forward(46.6666666667)

        self.pen.penup()

        self.pen.left(180)
        self.pen.forward(46.6666666667)

        self.pen.left(30)

    def right_arm(self):
        self.pen.right(90)

        self.pen.pendown()
        self.pen.forward(46.6666666667)

        self.pen.penup()

    def check(self, value):
        if value == 5:
            self.circle()
        elif value == 4:
            self.body()
        elif value == 3:
            self.left_leg()
        elif value == 2:
            self.right_leg()
        elif value == 1:
            self.left_arm()

The check function is the only function that is called in the main file.
I did notice whenever I tried it in the 'package' file I made with the class, it automatically closes after initialization because I'm not doing anything with it.
However, in the main file whenever I initialize my class (the variable at the top named hangman) it stays even if I don't put it in a loop or do anything with it. (during testing)
When I remove everything associated with the class and the 'package' file the game works just fine.

"This code ran 4-5 times without a problem, but it does not anymore" -- are you using git to track your code changes? If you are, then bisect or step through your commits until you find a good one. If not, now might be a good time to begin learning git.

is the package file in the same folder as the main code ?

I think you can just remove turtle.done(), which is a (confusingly named) alias of turtle.mainloop(), which is an infinite loop.

The import package works fine. In fact in my testing i simply replaced this with the actual class (just in case).
The error turns out to be in the loop.
I fixed this by using turtle.bye() instead of turtle.done().
This succesfully terminates the loop.
this is the (new) code for the loop:
while running:
    guess = str(input(f"Enter your letter: ")).lower()

    if len(guess) == 1:
        if guess in listed_word:
            for index, letter in enumerate(listed_word):
                if letter == guess:
                    blanks_list = list(blanks)

                    blanks_list[index] = guess
                    blanks = ''.join(blanks_list)

            print(blanks)

            if blanks == word:
                print("You win!")
                turtle.bye()
                running = False
        else:
            if lives != 0:
                lives -= 1
                hangman.check(lives)

            if lives > 0:
                print(f"You have {lives} lives left.")
            else:
                print("Game over!")
                turtle.bye()
                running = False
    else:
        pass


No need for else: pass. I'd flatten the nesting out by inverting the top condition and using continue. You can also just remove turtle.bye() and it should behave as expected by breaking the loop with running = False and letting control reach the end of the script.

nice additional points @ggorlen. That would tidy up the code neatly in addition to fixing the immidiate bug.
